# Qt : No rule to make target '../controlpanel.ui', needed by 'ui_controlpanel.h'. Stop

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

I met very strange problem on the Qt Creator.

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target '../controlpanel.ui', needed by 'ui_controlpanel.h'.  Stop.


mingw32-make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../controlpanel.ui', needed by 'ui_controlpanel.h'.  Stop.
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
22:43:11: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
```

This project compiled well before. But now I got compile error.
I use Qt creator 5.4.0 on Windows.

And specially, this project compiled without any error on the Qt Creator 5.4.0 of Mac version.

**What was wrong? How can I solve this error?**

This is a qmake file.

```
QT       += core gui opengl network multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = LaserdockVisualizer
TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += .

# dwarf-2 for profiling
#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -gdwarf-2

include(../../LaserdockCore/LaserdockCore.pri)
QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.10

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    LaserdockVisualizer/LaserdockVisualizerDelegate.cpp \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Form/LaserdockMainWindow.cpp \
    ...
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Appakabar/Test/ldAppakabarTestSoundEventUtilVisualizer.cpp \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Appakabar/Test/ldAppakabarTestSoundEventUtilVisualizerControlPanel.cpp

HEADERS += \
    LaserdockVisualizer/LaserdockVisualizerDelegate.h \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Form/LaserdockMainWindow.h \
    ...
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Appakabar/Test/ldAppakabarTestSoundEventUtilVisualizer.h \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Appakabar/Test/ldAppakabarTestSoundEventUtilVisualizerControlPanel.h


FORMS += \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Form/LaserdockMainWindow.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Form/ldVisualizerControlPanelEmpty.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/ld3dCubeVisualizerControlPanel.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Test/ldTestControlVisualizerControlPanel.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Feldspar/ldWalkerVisualizerControlPanel.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Test/ldTestCircleVisualizerControlPanel.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Feldspar/test/ldMusicReactorTestVisualizerControlPanel.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Feldspar/test/ldFrameTestVisualizerControlPanel.ui \
    LaserdockVisualizer/Visualizations/Visualizers/Appakabar/Test/ldappakabartestsoundeventutilvisualizercontrolpanel.ui
```

Comment: show your qmake project files

Comment: @UmNyobe I appended my qmake file.

Comment: all .ui files in the project makes such above error.

Comment: Have you tried removing  QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.10 , since you're compiling for Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution.

On Qt Creator, go into "Projects Tab", then you can see "Shadow build". Uncheck this and compile. The error disappears.

Comment: That fixed the issue! I had added a file by mistake, then deleted it and also did a `git rm <file>`, and it removed all traces of that file from git as well as my `.pro` file, still this error was coming. Doing this fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

[covernal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28782010/4714742) works fine if you are only targeting one platform. If, however, you are compiling for multiple platforms (e.g., Desktop & Android) you can keep doing the shadow build. Here's how I fixed it:

Find the project's build directory from the Projects tab:
[image]

Go to that directory and delete everything you find.
Qt will simply recreate all the files it needs to rebuild your project.